# Toggling multiple dates in asp calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a page that will have 12 calendars.
One for each month.
Is there a way I can allow the user to click on days and this will toggle them from red to blue. Then when  I postback on the server I want to be able to see the days marked in red.

How can something like this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default ASP.NET calendar control does not support this.

However, there is a custom control that may help you. I haven't used it myself, so I can't vouch for it entirely.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1032656/1420001.aspx

Comment: I copied this into a cs file but how do I see it in my toolbox?

Comment: You may need to manually add it in the ASPX file. I never use the toolbox, so I'm not sure if there is a way to make it appear in the toolbox. You can try looking [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28783/Your-First-ASP-NET-Custom-Control) for instructions on registering custom controls.